# UISplitView and custom toolbar at bottom

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

So I have a Split View controller and am trying to put a toolbar at the bottom of my root view programmatically.  I am currently adding it to the bottom of the table using the `[self.tableView setTableFooterView:toolbar];` method.  This works fine getting the toolbar on the screen, but it is not anchored to the bottom of the view.  It always appears after the last element in the table.  How would I go about anchoring it to the bottom of the root view?  Should I set the frame to the bottom of the view, and then add it as a subview to the rootview itself?  Or can I just adjust the frame and leave it as a component of the TableFooterView?  Thanks

Comment: I guess what I really need is someway to make it fixed to the bottom of the tableview, aka not scroll.

Comment: Are you asking about the master or detail part of the split view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right solution in your question.

Set the frame of your toolbar to the bottom of your root view.  Be sure and make sure it's the frontmost view by calling:

```
[myRootView bringSubviewToFront:myBarView];
```

Comment: How exactly can you set it to the bottom of the view without hardcoding the coordinates in?  The size of the view will change if it's in portrait mode and the user presses the display button.

Comment: The problem when I add it as a subview to the rootview, it is still not fixed.  It scrolls with the table...